# In TypeScript, how can I automatically assign object properties to my class?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a class as follows:

```
class Company {

    name: string;
    url: string;
    address: string

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

I then retrieve an object from a database which I know contain some or all of the properties of my class eg

```
{name: "Acme", url: "www.acme.com"}
```

Is there a way that I can automatically construct my class from the object?

At the moment, I know I can do something like:

```
    const company = new Company();
    const object = {name: "Acme", url: "www.acme.com"}; // in reality retrieve from database
    for (const key in object) {
        if (key == "name") {
            company.name = object[key];
        }
        if (key == "url") {
            company.url = object[key];
        }

    }
```

But this is not very elegant and become unwieldy over a larger volume of object properties.

Is there an automatic way to do this?

Comment: have you considered `Object.assign` ?

Comment: Yes but I'm not copying object to object, but rather object to class so I'm not sure it would work

Comment: You only need properties which are present on your class to be copied over?

Comment: Yes, only properties present in my class

Comment: Okay, just declaring `name: string;` doesn't actually do anything. It's erased at compile time. You need to assign a default value to your members, then use `Object.keys` on *your* object, and copy things over from your db result object.

Comment: If `Company` has no methods then it shouldn't be a class in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting from your approach:

```
const company = new Company();
const someObject = { name: "Acme", url: "www.acme.com" };

let legitKeys: Array<keyof Company> = [
    'name','address','url'
];

for (const key in someObject) {
    if (legitKeys.indexOf(key as keyof Company) !== -1) {
        company[key] = someObject[key];   
    }
}
```

The 'keyof Company'-Type works as a safety-net, so that you can not add strings to the legitKeys array that are not a key of Company by accident.

I feel that there is still a better way, e.g. a more elegant way for writing that if-statement.

To get rid of the compiler-error with noImplicitAny you can use this (still feels like one can do better):

```
class Company implements IndexSignature { 
    [key: string]: any;
    ...
 }

interface IndexSignature {
    [key: string]: any;
}

const someObject = {
    name: "Acme", url: "www.acme.com"
} as IndexSignature;
```

Comment: More elegant than what I have but I get a compiler error - "[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Company' has no index signature."

Comment: This occurs if you have noImplicitAny configured as true in your tsconfig. You can either remove that setting or adapt the code to have an Index-Signature, i will update my answer.